# asp.net Enterprise Library, All connections in use (closed)

Tags: asp.net

im using the asp.net Enterprise Library to insert and update data to an sql database.

c# code:

```
Database db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase();
IDbConnection connection = db.GetConnection();
connection.Open();
IDbTransaction transaction = connection.BeginTransaction();
DBCommandWrapper command;

try
{
//insert part
command = db.GetStoredProcCommandWrapper("stored_procedure1");
command.CommandTimeout = 900;
command.AddInParameter("@parameter1", DbType.Int32, 3);
db.ExecuteNonQuery(command, transaction);

//update part
command = db.GetStoredProcCommandWrapper("stored_procedure2");
command.CommandTimeout = 900;
command.AddInParameter("@param1", DbType.Int32, 5);
db.ExecuteNonQuery(command, transaction);

transaction.Commit();
}
catch (SqlException e)
{
  transaction.Rollback();
  throw (new ApplicationException("sql error", e));
}
catch (Exception e)
{
  transaction.Rollback();
  throw (new ApplicationException("error", e));
}
finally
{
connection.Close();
}
```

the code is on a method.
The method is executed many times and sometimes im getting error:
"Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool. This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached."

My questions are: Is it ok to have the insert and update part together as it is above?

Having the insert and update part together is causing this error?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you do not roll back your transaction on error.

Secondly in order to guarantee that your finally block is called you need to add the catch block.

```
Try {
...
}
Catch {
}
finally {
close connection
}
```

Read the second paragraph of the link located below

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zwc8s4fz(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zwc8s4fz%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: I'm getting the error when implementing the application on another machine.

How can I reproduce the error locally?
I have the application solution and im debugging on Visual Studio 2008.
I mean, Limiting the pool size would help me getting the error locally?

Comment: In order to try and reproduce the error message you could probably create a load test on the application to simulate multiple users hitting the site. Is there any error messages in the Application logs. Check those too.

Comment: The are no multiple users. That's not the scenario. On the machine where the error shows there is only one user using the application. The user clicks on a button on a form, every time the button is clicked it "calls" the method which contains the code above. The user keeps clicking the button until the error shows. So, its like the method is taking all the connections from the pool until there is nothing left...........Right now i cannot access the Application logs because I dont have access to the machine.

Comment: I will try monitoring the website. Thanks!